# Associativity in matrix multiplication with a scalar? Express $(w^Tx)x$ as $Aw$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, also, I have $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. I have the expression $(w^Tx)x$. My question is how can I express that in the form $Aw$ where $A$ is some matrix?

I tried using the associative rule, but it obviously doesn't work because $w^Tx$ is a scalar, but $x$ is a vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve almost got it. Since $w^Tx$ is a scalar, it commutes with the vector $x$, so that $$(w^Tx)x = x(w^Tx) = x(x^Tw) = (xx^T)w.$$ The parenthesized term on the right of this equation is an $n\times n$ matrix. (This also uses $w^Tx=x^Tw$.)

Strictly speaking, only left-multiplication by scalars is part of the definition of a vector space, but since the underlying field is commutative, right-multiplication by scalars is often taken for granted as also being valid.